# Using LVM2 RAID on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, raid, lvm

I would like to use LVM2's built-in RAID support (`lvconvert -m1 --type raid1 vgname/lvname`) on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.  Unfortunately this feature appeared in LVM2 2.02.89 (assuming I've read the [changelog](https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/lvm2.git/tree/WHATS_NEW) correctly), while Ubuntu 12.04 has LVM2 2.02.66.

What are my options?  Is there a backport of newer LVM2 somewhere?  Will a newer lvm2 package require a newer kernel than the one in 12.04, or are these features managed in userspace somehow?

Answer (score 0):

A backported LVM package seems safe enough. If the kernel doesn't support the md/dm integration, I expect it will fail the conversion step, at which point you could just backport the kernel too.